# Remove Varying levels of empty XML tags in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery, xml.modify

I am using FOR XML EXPLICIT to union to convert some SQL table info into an XML file. It's all working, but I have loads of empty tags in the results, at all sorts of different levels. I would like to remove all the empty tags, but keep the top level for each group. Here's an example of the sort of thing I mean:

Using this example bit of nonsense XML, I can remove the bottom level empty nodes with a .modify xquery:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = 
'<Whatever>
  <GlassesTypes>
      <GlassesType />
  </GlassesTypes>
  <ExpressionOfJoy>
      <FellOver>Y</FellOver>
  </ExpressionOfJoy>
  <Flights>
    <Flight>
      <Bookings>
        <Booking>
          <Segments>
            <Segment />
          </Segments>
        </Booking>
      </Bookings>
    </Flight>
  </Flights>
</Whatever>'

SELECT @XML as Before

SET  @Xml.modify('delete //*[not(node())]');

SELECT @XML AS After
```

This has done exactly what I want with 'GlassesTypes', but there are still levels of empty nodes in 'Flights'. I could repeat the same modify command over and over for each level to get up to the point where only 'Flights' is displayed, but doing so will delete the 'GlassesTypes' empty placeholder:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = 
'<Whatever>
  <GlassesTypes>
      <GlassesType />
  </GlassesTypes>
  <ExpressionOfJoy>
      <FellOver>Y</FellOver>
  </ExpressionOfJoy>
  <Flights>
    <Flight>
      <Bookings>
        <Booking>
          <Segments>
            <Segment />
          </Segments>
        </Booking>
      </Bookings>
    </Flight>
  </Flights>
</Whatever>'

SELECT @XML as Before

SET  @Xml.modify('delete //*[not(node())]');
SET  @Xml.modify('delete //*[not(node())]');
SET  @Xml.modify('delete //*[not(node())]');
SET  @Xml.modify('delete //*[not(node())]');
SET  @Xml.modify('delete //*[not(node())]');

SELECT @XML AS After
```

Is there any way in which I can delete all empty nodes, until the penultimate empty node, regardless of how many levels a group contains? The ideal result would be this:

```
<Whatever>
  <GlassesTypes />
  <ExpressionOfJoy>
      <FellOver>Y</FellOver>
  </ExpressionOfJoy>
  <Flights />
</Whatever>
```

In this example, there is only 'Whatever' tag, but in the real data, there might be several repeated, all with different levels of information, encompassed by a root tag or equivalent.

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your version of "empty" as not containing any descendant attribute or text nodes, instead of as not containing any descendant nodes. Then retain children of `<Whatever>` by only selecting descendants of its children:

```
/Whatever/*//*[empty(.//text() | .//attribute())]
```

Comment: Hi, THanks for the answer; could you clarify what the actual line of script would look like, please? I'm sorry, I have not used xquery much before - you left me behind slightly!

Comment: @HighPlainsGrifter That's just the XPath that follows `delete`, in place of `//*[not(node())]`. You should only need to execute this once.

Comment: Gotcha - I tried that and it gave an error telling me that the XQuery syntax 'attribute()' is not supported, so I figured I must have done something wrong. However, I am specifically not using attributes in my XML, so that's fine; I have removed that bit to leave "SET @XML.modify('delete /Whatever/*//*[empty(.//text())]')" which works perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @HighPlainsGrifter Hm, maybe `attribute()` is XSLT 2.0, not sure. If you were to need to keep elements with attributes, you could try replacing `.//attribute()` with `.//@*`, and that should be supported.