# XML Stylesheet to remove all empty child nodes, but keep parent level

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some xml, represented by this example:

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<Whatever xmlns ="http://tempuri.org/Whatever.xsd">
  <GlassesTypes>
      <GlassesType />
  </GlassesTypes>
  <ExpressionOfJoy>
      <FellOver>Y</FellOver>
  </ExpressionOfJoy>
  <Flights>
    <Flight>
      <Bookings>
        <Booking>
          <Segments>
            <Segment />
          </Segments>
        </Booking>
      </Bookings>
    </Flight>
  </Flights>
  <Fruit>
    <Apples>
      <RedOnes>
        <RedOne />
      </RedOnes>
      <GreenOnes>
        <GreenOne>
          <Name>Granny Smith</Name>
          <Seedless />
        </GreenOne>
      </GreenOnes>
    </Apples>
    <Pears />
  </Fruit>
</Whatever>
```

In [[This previous question]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25627732/remove-varying-levels-of-empty-xml-tags-in-sql-server) I asked how to use an xquery to remove all the empty child tags at varying levels, leaving only the parent tag as a place holder. Unfortunately, while I was able to implement this solution, I have had to add to it considerably in order to correctly format my xml and it is slowing everything down a lot.

The answer seems to be to stop mucking around with the xml in SQL server and just make a stylesheet to transform the xml as required. I have acheived quite a lot here and things are looking good, but I have not found the right way to remove the child elements at each level while still leaving the parent in place. All the searches I have found remove the child elements and the parent as well.

For instance, I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="fn xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(string(.)) != ''">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but the result leaves no empty nodes at all. I am using [[freeformatter]](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html#ad-output) to check my results. Here is what I would like as an output (as you can see, the parents of the empty nodes are still there as empty placeholders):

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<Whatever xmlns ="http://tempuri.org/Whatever.xsd">
  <GlassesTypes />
  <ExpressionOfJoy>
      <FellOver>Y</FellOver>
  </ExpressionOfJoy>
  <Flights />
  <Fruit>
    <Apples>
      <RedOnes />
      <GreenOnes>
        <GreenOne>
          <Name>Granny Smith</Name>
          <Seedless />
        </GreenOne>
      </GreenOnes>
    </Apples>
    <Pears />
  </Fruit>
</Whatever>
```

I have been looking at identity templates and how to use them [here](http://www.xmlplease.com/xsltidentity), and pages [all](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200403/post50720.html) [over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965491/remove-child-node-results-in-empty-parent-node) the place, but they all seem to require that levels are referred to by name in order to achieve what I would need something a bit more non-specific I think, to apply to all levels of a large xml file. Any suggestions most welcome!

**Edit**

the logic behind keeping or removing an element is that for each element, if there is no data in any of its child elements, then its child elements should be removed.

for instance; you could interpret this logic as applied from the lowest level child element all the way up to the highest element to contain only empty child elements. Thus `GlassesType` is removed as an empty child of `GlassesTypes`, but `GlassesTypes` remains as it now has no empty child elements. Likewise `Segment` is removed, but this leaves `Bookings` with an empty child element `Segments`, which should be removed and so on up to `Flights`. `Seedless`, which has no empty child elements, remains.

Mark

Comment: Why are `<GlassesTypes />` and `<Flights/>` included in your output?

Comment: Or, conversely, why are `<Bookings>`, `<Booking>` and `<Segments>` excluded from your output?

Comment: We wanted to include the empty placeholders to facilitate usage of the xml file further down the line, for the recipients. If this is not going to be a feasible thing to achieve, we can change this requirement. We were going to import the xml into Excel for some of our customers who are not familiar with xml, and this seems much easier if you have a consistent set of placeholders on every example.

Comment: The problem right now is that your requirement is not clear. I cannot come up with a logical rule that would exclude `<Segments>` but keep `<GlassesTypes>`.

Comment: I have edited the question to include a better explanation of the logic

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you need a variation on the identity transform template, such as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*[descendant::text()]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit:

***in response to your clarification:***

> ... for each element, if there is no data in any of its child elements,
>   then its child elements should be removed.

Ok, if you put it like that, then let's change that template slightly to:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="descendant::text()">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that remove the `Flights` element in the sample XML input while the wanted results has it as `<Flights />`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Indeed I am puzzled about that, as well as about <`GlassesTypes />`.